# How to prevent an element from moving diagonally

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The element moves all the directions (top, right, bottom, left) including diagonally. I **do not** want it to move diagonally.

HTML

```
<body onload="move('theDiv')">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="theDiv" class="theDiv"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var dragValue;

function move(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById("theDiv");

    element.style.position = "sticky";
    element.onmousedown = function() {
        dragValue = element;
    };
}

document.onmouseup = function(e) {
    dragValue = null;
};

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX,
        y = e.pageY;
            
    dragValue.style.transform = "transltex(" + x + "px)";
    dragValue.style.transform = "transltey(" + y + "px)";
};
```

Comment: `transltex`? `transltey`? You mean `translateX` and `translateY`?

Comment: Sounds to me as though you want to complete on transform before starting on the other.

Comment: Do you want to make it move exclusively on one axis at a time? Like first drag is only up/down or left/right and then next click and drag can be another direction? Or if I wanted to move diagonally, can I move up and then right in the same click and drag?

Comment: yes i mean translateX and translateY, i tried dragValue.style.top and dragValue.style.left, both of them give me the complete movement to all directions, while i want to prevent the element from moving diagonally

Comment: @BrettEast, i want to click on the element then move it up or down or left right only, in one click

Comment: Okay, so just confirming that moving in an 'L' shape is fine, but not a diagonal? I think that's going to be a little harder, I imagine you're going to have to track the pixel position like half a second earlier to try and determine if the user is trying to move up/down or left/right and then only update that `transform` prop.

Comment: Consider: A diagonal in discrete / digital / pixel / cell space is just a zillion little 'L' shapes. A single click-and-drag allowing both a horizontal and vertical move without needing to stop and click again, but not allowing diagonal, will have to use some kind of threshold of time/movement; for example "you can't change directions until you have moved X distance"

Comment: thanks to everyone who tried to solve this issue, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **lastPoint**.

**1.** When the value of x in the current position is not equal to the value of x in the old position, that is, moving in the direction of the x-axis.

**2.** When the value of y of the current position is not equal to the value of y of the old position, it means moving in the direction of the y-axis.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
    .theDiv {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 100px;
      width: 150px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="move('theDiv')">

  <div id="theDiv" class="theDiv"></div>

  <script>
    var dragValue;
    var lastPoint;

    function move(id) {
      var element = document.getElementById("theDiv");
      element.onmousedown = function(e) {
        dragValue = element;
        lastPoint = e;
        lastPoint.pageX = lastPoint.pageX - ($('#theDiv').width() / 2);
        lastPoint.pageY = lastPoint.pageY - ($('#theDiv').height() / 2);
      };
    }

    document.onmouseup = function(e) {
      dragValue = null;
      lastPoint = null;
    };

    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
      if (dragValue != null) {
        var x = e.pageX - ($('#theDiv').width() / 2),
          y = e.pageY - ($('#theDiv').height() / 2);
        if (lastPoint.pageX == e.pageX)
          dragValue.style.top = y + "px";
        else
          dragValue.style.left = x + "px";
        lastPoint = e;
      }
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

*I had to change your code a bit to be able to run it. You can easily use this code or use it with your own code*

Comment: Chrome on Windows 10 - 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined

Comment: Because dragValue was mousemove event is null, it does not give an error now.

Comment: @MeysamAsadi thanks a lot for helping me solve this issue, I'm very thankful.